# Does "unexpectedly" apply to one or both following verb phrases?

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity

We're having a discussion in a forum on rulings in duplicate bridge. In duplicate bridge, each partnership has their own set of bidding system agreements, and there are regulations that specify that certain bids must be alerted, depending on what their meanings are (usually, common agreements are not alerted, while unusual agreements are). In the English Bridge Union, these regulations are in the [Blue Book](http://view.pagetiger.com/ebu-blue-book/2014), and it states that the following is not alertable:

> [4C1] (c) A pass which does not unexpectedly convey values or specify suit holdings.

The question has come up in [our discussion](http://www.bridgebase.com/forums/topic/70445-passing-a-doubled-transfer/page__view__findpost__p__840344) over whether *unexpectedly* applies only to *convey values* or also includes *specify suit holdings*.

I argued that it applies to both, because there are easy ways for them to reword it to indicate otherwise, and also because there are many common situations where a pass implies suit holdings that I don't believe the regulators intended to require an alert.

But another poster suggested that they could simply have repeated *unexpectedly* before each verb phrase to indicate clearly that both are intended, and he doesn't seem to agree with my extension to the other situations (which hinges on how precisely *specify suit holdings* should be interpreted).

Is the actual wording truly ambiguous, or should it normally be interpreted one way or the other?

Comment: I think this is a case where context makes the meaning clear. Why would you need to alert a pass that ***expectedly*** specified suit holdings? If your partner bids three hearts, and you're happy with it (and don't think you can make four), why would you need to alert the opponents that you aren't very short in hearts.

Comment: @PeterShor There are some instances where we alert expected meanings, usually because addressing all the possible cases makes the alerting regulations harder to remember. So to keep them simpler, they usually address broad categories, and sometimes common meanings are included in the alertable cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with either of the two sentence structures associated with the meanings you're concerned with, so it's grammatically ambiguous.  There could be something special about the context and the way such rules are customarily interpreted that eliminates one of the readings, I suppose, but that wouldn't be a grammatical issue.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more general answer, since the argument is occurring among people who are experienced in interpreting bridge laws and regulations, and we don't agree on how the context implies it should go.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the infinitive for "specify" indicates it is connected to "does not unexpectedly," which is an ***do*-auxiliary umbrella for both main verb**s, "convey" and "specify."

This is **not**:

*A pass [which **does not unexpectedly convey** values] or [[which] **specifies**] suit holdings.*

where decoupling might be in effect.

No ambiguity to me.

Comment: 'A dog which does not noisily bark or bite', with the adverb modifying only the first infinitive, seems acceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If the adverb can't sensibly apply to both verbs, that's an obvious exception. Although I'd write that as _does not bark noisily or bite_. Analogously, the original sentence could have been _does not convey unexpected values or specify suit holdings_

Comment: @Barmar But Marius says 'The use of the infinitive for "specify" indicates it is connected to "does not unexpectedly" ' (he does not mention semantic constraints). I'm giving an example that shows that that's not necessarily true.

Comment: "does not convey unexpected values" is NOT the same as "does not unexpectedly convey  values"